# Is writing JavaScript code differ from other OS's?

Tags: javascript

I have following code snippet from the book [Eloquent JavaScript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/), chapter *18. Forms and Form Fields* where it suppose to **insert a string on keydown**.

```
// Input field
<textarea></textarea>

// The following code wires up
// a <textarea> tag with an event handler that, when you press F2, inserts
// the string “Khasekhemwy” for you.

var textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');
textarea.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
// The key code for F2 happens to be 113
if (event.keydown == 113) {
    replaceSelection(textarea, "Khasekhemwy");
    event.preventDefault();
    }
});

// The replaceSelection function replaces the currently selected part of a
// text field’s content with the given word and then moves the cursor after
// that word so that the user can continue typing.

function replaceSelection(field, word ) {
    var from = field.selectionStart, to = field.selectionEnd;
    field.value = field.value.slice(0, from ) + word +
                                field.value.slice(to);
    // Put the c u r s o r after the word
    field.selectionStart = field.selectionEnd = from + word.length;
}
```

I'm on Macintosh computer using latest browsers and I'm starting to sense that it's either different OS that this code was written on or it's the code.

Note: Calling F2 on Macintosh  = `fn + F2`

Comment: is this only when you call `F*` or any other key as well?

Comment: what is the value of `event.key`?

Comment: event does not have keydown-property that is why it is not working.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The correct answer will be yes. But not in the scope of your question.

JS executing result based who will execute your JS. In your question you are working with DOM, so I assume you work with browser. In this case browser will be your executor and executing result can be different (especially with DOM operations) depending on browser.

The second point is that not always we execute JS in the scope of the browser. Another common approach in to use Node.Js. In this case executing can be different for different versions of the Node.

And the third point. Windows (as an OS) can execute JS by itself. So result of this executing will be totally different with Mac :).

Please note, that JS is not a compiling, so the same code can behave differently in different environments.

Comment: I found your answer useful according to this [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Tools_and_testing/Cross_browser_testing/JavaScript)

Comment: @DomK It is about this and a bit more. Because JS really depends on the executor.

Answer (score 2):

You have mistyped the code (when copying?). It should read  `if (event.keyCode == 113)` instead of `if (event.keydown == 113)`.

`event.keydown` probably always evaluates to `undefined`, thus the condition is never true.

Comment: That said, using keyCode is also deprecated: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode "This feature has been removed from the Web standards. Though some browsers may still support it, it is in the process of being dropped. Avoid using it and update existing code if possible; see the compatibility table at the bottom of this page to guide your decision. Be aware that this feature may cease to work at any time."